# error when restarting Apache webserver

Tags: php, apache, windows-7, restart

I installed Apache web server successfully.When I type the local host in browser it shows that it works. And then I save the php file to server httpdocs and restart it shows the the following alert.

> Apache monitor is Already Started.

Please let me know where I am going wrong ?

Comment: why httpdocs directory ?

Comment: sorry i save my php file to htdocs

Comment: in What environment u are working?

Comment: i never using any IDE now.just iwant instal php with apache in windows7?

Comment: question seems more suited for [serverfault](http://serverfault.com), flagged to move to serverfault so that it gets the needed attention.

Comment: but when i running in the browse it shows the sucessmessage?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to restart Apache every time you save a php file in httpdocs. just refresh you browser.

Comment: then I guess something is wrong with the whole server's configuration. try re-installing it. Apache runs as a service in windows, so it is possible that another program (perhaps tuneUp or an antivirous) is interfering with it

Comment: restart your system , and try accessing the php file using localhost , and let us know what do you get

Comment: please send any recommended tool for develop php apps with Apache server

Comment: wen i restart the system i am getting the same problem ?